# What's the grammatical construction of "to see..."?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> **To see the Clyde below, leading into the distance and knowing that it connects to the Atlantic and the world beyond, fills** me with optimism. It reminds me the world is much bigger than where I currently am.

[Source](https://www.heraldscotland.com/news/18984914.manjot-sumal-scot-squad-star-loves-lyle-hill-greenock/)

---

What's the grammatical construction of the bold part?

Comment: It's a clause defining the experience that makes the speaker feel optimistic.

Comment: @KateBunting "**Leading into the distance**" modifies "**Clyde below**" but "**knowing that it connects to the Atlantic and the world beyond**" doesn't. Therefore, I think that "**knowing**" is grammatically incorrect. What do you say?

Comment: Yes, strictly speaking it should be "...and to know that it connects..." - but this is informal English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the top-level structure, with distracting bits removed:

*[To see...] and [knowing...] fills...*

So the subject of the sentence is a *noun phrase* where the *conjunction* "and" joins the two noun phrases "To see..." and "knowing..." into a single noun phrase.

"leading into the distance" modifies "the Clyde" in the first element of the compound noun. "Knowing..." is in the second element of the compound noun, and is not joined with "leading", though it's easy to read it that way since they have the same "-ing" form.

If this were formal writing, it would likely read, ["To see..."] and ["to know..."]